# Variables Multiplication for the factorial calculation

Tags: bash, multiplication, factorial

I'm making a script that calculates the factorial for a given number, but I'm having some problems with the multiplication.

Note: the factorial for is given by: `9!=9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1`

Here's my code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "Insert an Integer"

read input

if ! [[ "$input" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then
   exec >&2; echo "Error: You didn't enter an integer"; exit 1
fi

function factorial
{
while [ "$input" != 1 ];
do
    result=$(($result * $input))
    input=$(($input-1))
done
}
factorial
echo "The Factorial of " $input "is" $result
```

it keeps giving me errors of all kinds for different multiplication technics :/

Currently the output is:

> ```
> joaomartinsrei@joaomartinsrei ~/Área de Trabalho/Shell $ 
> ./factorial.sh
> Insert an Integer
> 3
> ./factorial.sh: line 15: * 3: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "* 3")
> The factorial of 3 is
> ```

Comment: What errors does it give you?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The main problem is that you never initialize `result` (to `1`), so this:

```
result=$(($result * $input))
```

is equivalent to this:

```
result=$(( * $input))
```

which is not a valid arithmetic expression.

Comment: Many Thanks Guys! It Worked like a charm one I initialized result :)