# How to convert dotted version number to an integer?

Tags: linux, bash, math

I want to store this value 3.4.1 as 3004001 so 3*1,000,000 + 4*1,000 + 1

I want to do this is a bash script how can I do that?

Comment: show your efforts

Comment: `sed 's/\./00/g'`

Comment: [Bash multiplication and addition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/299321/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), [Multiplication on command line terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11039876/608639), [Variables Multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15213127/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
val="3.4.1"
awk -F. '{ print ($1*1000000)+($2*1000+1) }' <<< $val
```

Use awk to split the data with field delimiter . and then perform the necessary math printing the result.